# Playwright with Groovy gives type error on BrowserContext.setDefaultTimeout

Tags: groovy, playwright, playwright-java

I'm trying to set a timeout for Playwright. The API [docs](https://playwright.dev/java/docs/1.19/api/class-browsercontext#browser-context-set-default-timeout) say `BrowserContext.setDefaultTimeout(timeout)` takes a double as `timeout`.

My code:

```
import com.microsoft.playwright.Browser
import com.microsoft.playwright.BrowserContext
import com.microsoft.playwright.BrowserType
import com.microsoft.playwright.Frame
import com.microsoft.playwright.Page
import com.microsoft.playwright.Playwright
import com.microsoft.playwright.impl.*

boolean isHeadless = false

Playwright playwright = Playwright.create()
Browser browser = playwright.chromium().launch(new BrowserType.LaunchOptions().setHeadless(isHeadless)
                                       .setSlowMo(50)
                                       .setChromiumSandbox(true)
                                       .setTimeout(30000)
                                       )
                                                             
Page page = browser.newPage()
double globalTimeout = 360000.00
BrowserContext.setDefaultTimeout(globalTimeout)

page.navigate("myURL")

page.fill("//input[@id='Email']", 'myUser')
page.fill("//input[@id='Password']", 'myPass')
page.click("//button[@id='btnLogin']")

assert page.title() == 'Investor Centre', report()

page.click("//a[contains(@key,'OMU,CRL5CWP4mn6TabH8MyTE-A2')]")
```

Results in:

```
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static com.microsoft.playwright.BrowserContext.setDefaultTimeout() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Double) values: [360000.0]
```

Comment: Can you add your whole code and we can easy reproduce it. Also link  to the doc is giving 404. The new one is https://playwright.dev/java/docs/api/class-browsercontext#browser-context-set-default-timeout

Comment: @MeT I added all my Groovy code.